# Q: Merge Request [mappeddrive] and [drivemapping]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I can see how they might be a little different: 'DriveMapping' might refer to the actual act of mapping/mounting a drive while 'MappedDrive' may refer specifically to drives already mapped, but people seem to be using them interchangeably on questions here already.

Should these be merged together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[drivemapping](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/drivemapping) had only a few question, merged into [mappeddrive](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mappeddrive) now.